# Facebook Like Plugin has stop to work on post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Example: this post has 27 likes on Facebook right now:

https://www.facebook.com/160210837333829/posts/712679778753596

but if I check the link with the Facebook's [Like Button Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) it says 0 likes. Why? Should I insert another link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

The like button plugin takes the url, which you gave to it and counts how many times it appeared in a post and was liked, how many times it was shared, commented and so on at the facebook page. That means, if you give the url `http://www.example.com/`, it will count all the likes, comments and shares that were given/made to a post which include this certain url.

So, probably your post has 27 likes, but the page you checked with the plugin (the facebook-url, it's not the same as the post!) does not have been shared, liked or whatever on facebook itself (I know, it's a bit complicated).

I think the better alternative for you would be embedding the post. 
[Here is a nice tutorial for this.](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/how-to-embed-post-facebook-quick-tip-ht)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to embed my post! I just need to put a "like" that refers to that post (so, giving the numbers of like, and like it directly). I think I can do it...! In less words: Like a post on Facebook with the plugin.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I've shortly googled but there's no way to do this (otherwise the user would probably not see what he is liking effectifly). You need to embed the whole post, so the user is able to see "what" he actually likes.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're trying to create a like button related to a facebook post, the like button only works with websites and facebook pages

You can accomplish something similar creating a facebook app and do a graph api call, after the user granted you the permissions of course.